# Static files are not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I've tried to deploy my react app on nginx, server is up but static files are not loading. I've tried many things but not of them are working.

```
http {
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my-server.test;
  location /{
    root /srv/build;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like nginx is dumb when it comes to interpreting file types, resolved this issue by adding `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in http block.

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nginx-handbook.test;
  location /{
    root /srv/ty;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this nginx "being dumb".  I prefer an explicit configuration like that to "defaults" that most people forget are there or why they exist.  :)